# Launch terminal from bash and run program?

Tags: bash

When running a bash command from somewhere other than terminal how do you specify that a terminal should be open?

For example if I run `firefox` that works fine, but if I run `Ranger` nothing happens. I'm guessing it's because the later doesn't specify a GUI?

*Note: Ranger is a terminal based file browser*

Are there any good work arounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work?

```
gnome-terminal -e ranger
```

Comment: I tried this with nmap. It works for me, but it closes after executing the command. If this is not what you want you can change this behaviour with Terminal -> User Choices (or something equivalent) -> Profiles -> Edit -> Title and command (or something equivalent). http://i.stack.imgur.com/M0fgx.png

Comment: Perfect, as a note for future readers. I'm on Xubuntu and I just replaced 'gnome-terminal' with 'xfce4-terminal.  If you're on a non-standard ubuntu just figure out which terminal you have.

Comment: Doesn't work of you want to launch it from Nautilus script menu using sudo